# Bash array variables: [@] or [*]?

Tags: bash

```
bash-3.2$ echo astr | sed 'hah' | sed 's/s/z/'
sed: 1: "hah": extra characters at the end of h command
bash-3.2$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
0 1 0
bash-3.2$ echo astr | sed 'hah' | sed 's/s/z/'
sed: 1: "hah": extra characters at the end of h command
bash-3.2$ PIPERET=("${PIPESTATUS[*]}")
bash-3.2$ echo ${PIPERET[*]}
0 1 0
bash-3.2$
```

This indicates that `[*]` works fine. But [this tut](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) mentions to use `[@]` instead.

Are both equally valid?

Comment: See here (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) for the `PIPESTATUS[*]` vs `PIPESTATUS[@]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference matters mainly when the array elements contain spaces etc. and especially multiple spaces, and is only manifest when the expressions are enclosed in double quotes:

```
$ x=( '   a  b  c   ' 'd  e  f' )
$ printf "[%s]\n" "${x[*]}"
[   a  b  c    d  e  f]
$ printf "[%s]\n" "${x[@]}"
[   a  b  c   ]
[d  e  f]
$ printf "[%s]\n" ${x[@]}
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
[f]
$ printf "[%s]\n" ${x[*]}
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
[f]
$
```

Outside double quotes, there's no difference.  Inside double quotes, `*` means 'a single string' and `@` means 'array elements individually'.

It is closely analogous to the way `$*` and `$@` (and `"$*"` and `"$@"`) work.

See the `bash` manual on:

- [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)
- [special parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters)

Answer (score 2):

To quote [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

> If
>          subscript  is  @  or *, the word expands to all members of name.  These
>          subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes.   If
>          the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the
>          value of each array member separated by the first character of the  IFS
>          special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a sep-
>          arate word.  When there are no array  members,  ${name[@]}  expands  to
>          nothing.   If  the  double-quoted  expansion  occurs within a word, the
>          expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning  part  of
>          the  original  word,  and the expansion of the last parameter is joined
>          with the last part of the original word.